# Decir si un vector está ordenado o no

Tags: c, array, algoritmos

Muy buenas, ¿alguien puede echarme un mano y decirme por qué escriba lo que escriba siempre me sale el mismo mensaje: "El vector está ordenado de forma creciente."?

Aquí va el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void main () {

        int vector [10];
        int i, check;

        printf ("Introduce 10 números: ");
        for (i = 0; i <10; i ++) {
            scanf ("%d", &vector [i]);
        }

        i = 0;
        check = 0; 
        while ((i < 10) && (check == 0)) {
            if ((vector [i]) > (vector [i] + 1)) {
                check = 1;
            }
            i ++;
        }
        if (check == 1) {
            printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma decreciente.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma creciente.\n");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: ¿No querrías poner `if ((vector[i]) >(vector[i+1]))`? (es decir, sumar 1 al índice y no al valor)

Comment: Además, el mensaje sería, bien que está ordenado de forma creciente, o bien que no está ordenado de forma creciente (pero eso no implica que lo esté en forma decreciente)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Abulafia.
Es decir, que si hago `vector [i] > vector [i] +1` sumo `+1` al valor de la variable `vector`; en cambio, si hago `vector [i] > vector [i +1]` sumo `+1` al índice `i`, ¿verdad?

Comment: Te recomiendo que googlees sobre métodos de ordenamientos. Son muy útiles a la hora de realizar este tipo de problemas, método burbuja, inserción o árbol son algunos; sencillos de realizar. Un saludo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Espero que te sirva esta versión del programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define true 1
#define false 0

void main ()
{
    int i;
    int vector [SIZE];
    int last;
    int is_creciente = true;
    int is_decreciente = true;

    //
    // Leer vector
    //
    printf ("Introduce %d números: ", SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i <SIZE; i ++)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &vector [i]);
    }
    //
    // Hacer comprobaciones en el vector
    //
    last = vector[0];
    for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(vector[i] < last) is_creciente = false;
        if(vector[i] > last) is_decreciente = false;
        last = vector[i];
    }
    //
    // Imprimir resultados
    //
    if(is_creciente && is_decreciente)
        printf ("El vector tiene todos los valores repetidos.\n");
    else if(is_creciente)
        printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma creciente.\n");
    else if(is_decreciente)
        printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma decreciente.\n");
    else
        printf ("El vector está desordenado.\n");

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: ¿probastes poner los include de stdio.h, conio.h?

Comment: pues si, necesitas esas librerias para usar el printf, scanf, getch.

Comment: tambien depende del compilador, tal vez las variables 'last', 'is_creciente' y 'is_decreciente' tengas que declararlo al principio

Comment: Ya hice las modificaciones completas, lo probe en PellesC y en Visual C++,  y en ambos me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Para futuras respuestas, siempre es bueno explicarle al op lo que pasa en su código y cómo lo resuelves en tu versión del mismo, tal como lo hace eferion en su respuesta para esta pregunta, no se trata de que sólo me resuelvas el problema, sino de dejarme claro donde está el error, así no me vuelve a pasar.

Answer (score 6):

Tu programa tiene cuatro errores importantes.

El primero es que la comparación no es correcta:

```
if ((vector [i]) > (vector [i] + 1)) {
```

Si el vector tuviese dos valores:

```
2 1
```

El programa cogería en la primera iteración el valor `2` y compararía lo siguiente:

```
if( 2 > 2+1 )
```

Lo cual va a ser **falso**, puesto que `2` no es mayor que `3`. Con esta línea estás comparando un valor con "el valor más 1", lo que **siempre** te va a arrojar un valor **falso**. Como la condición no se va a cumplir nunca no se va a establecer `check=1`.

La comprobación que deberías hacer es más bien esta:

```
// Nota: he quitado los parentesis por claridad
if (vector[i] > vector[i+1]) {
```

De esta forma modificas el índice del vector en vez del valor de los elementos.

El segundo error tiene que ver con el rango de iteración:

```
while ((i < 10) && (check == 0)) {
```

Si el vector tiene 10 posiciones, las mismas serán accesibles en el rango (0,9). A simple vista parece correcto, ¿no? al fin y al cabo el algoritmo abandonará el bucle cuando `i==10`, lo cual es correcto pero ... ¿qué sucede cuando `i==9` en este otro punto?:

```
if (vector[i] > vector[i+1]) {
```

Sustituyendo `i` quedaría:

```
if (vector[9] > vector[10]) {
```

Y es facil ver que con `vector[10]` vamos a acceder a una posición que no pertenece al arreglo... Tienes que modificar el rango de iteración:

```
while ((i < 9) && (check == 0)) {
```

Vamos con el tercer error. Este es un error de concepto. El programa está tomando una base errónea:

```
check = 0; 
while ((i < 9) && (check == 0)) {
    if (vector[i] > vector[i+1]) {
        check = 1;
    }
    i ++;
}
```

En este caso el programa asume que, de primeras, el vector no va a estar ordenado y entenderá que está ordenado cuando se encuentre dos posiciones consecutivas que **sí** que están ordenadas. Lo que sucede es que puedes tener un vector desordenado en el que dos posiciones consecutivas sí que estén ordenadas:

```
1 4 3 7 2 9
  ^ ^
```

En el ejemplo, 4 es mayor que 3, luego a partir de ese punto tu algoritmo entenderá que el vector está ordenado... cuando claramente no lo está.

El punto de partida en este caso sería asumir que el vector va a estar ordenado y decidir que no lo está cuando te encuentres un caso en el que no se cumpla la ordenación:

```
check = 1; 
while ((i < 9) && (check == 0)) {
    if (vector[i] < vector[i+1]) {
        check = 0;
    }
    i ++;
}
```

Y, finalmente, el cuarto error:

```
if (check == 1) {
    printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma decreciente.\n");
}
else {
    printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma creciente.\n");
}
```

Salvo que te lo digan claramente en el ejercicio, asumir que un vector aleatorio va a estar o bien ordenado ascendentemente o bien descendentemente es demasiado asumir... te vuelvo a poner mi vector:

```
1 4 3 7 2 9
```

¿Qué ordenación tiene? No es ascendente... luego entonces es descendente ¿cierto? ¿o lo deberíamos plantear al reves? es decir... como no es descendente... ¿será ascendente? obviamente ni lo uno ni lo otro:

```
if (check == 1) {
    printf ("El vector está ordenado de forma creciente.\n");
}
else {
    printf ("El vector NO está ordenado de forma creciente.\n");
}
```

En el código que has puesto el algoritmo intentaba comprobar si el vector estaba ordenado de forma ascendente... luego lo único que puedes saber a ciencia cierta es si dicho vector tiene esa ordenación... cualquier otra ordenación será incierta y no podrás detectarla con este algoritmo

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo aborde como un sistema de puntos, si tienes 5 espacios a comparar la forma ascendente o descendente, se tendrán que hacer 4 comparaciones:

```
Indice    Valor   Comparaciones
 0           1      Indice0 > Indice1
 1           2      Indice1 > Indice2
 2           3      Indice2 > Indice3
 3           4      Indice3 > Indice4
 4           5
```

============================================================

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int n,num,ascen=0,cont = 1;
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros a almacenar: ");
    n = entrada.nextInt();
    
    int[] array = new int[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero: ");
        num = entrada.nextInt();
        array[i] = num;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){//Se haran "n-1" comparaciones ya que el ultimo valor no se compara
        if(array[i]< array[cont]){
            ascen++;//Si el array en la posicion i es menor que el que esta en la posicion siguiente
        }//Indica que va aumentando y se registra 1 punto
        cont++;
    }
    
    if(ascen==n-1){//Hacemos la comparacion final
        System.out.println("Si");//Si se tiene n cantidad de puntos iguales a el numero de comparaciones
    }else{//Indica que todos los numeros en el vector van de forma ascendente
        System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```